# react-google-charts with react-create-app not being properly installed through npm

Tags: reactjs, npm-install, create-react-app

I am currently developing a react app taking advantage of the create-react-app command as I am not familiar at all with the node stack. Everything has gone well so far but I am stuck with the fact that I am unable to have react-google-charts added properly to my project.

No error appears when executing the command:

```
npm i -s react-google-charts
```

But nothing has happened. There is no node_module added and there is no edition of package.json file neither.

So whenever I place the quick samples given in:

https://github.com/RakanNimer/react-google-charts
(I mean any inclusion of any react-google-chart element)

I got the error:

> Error in .... Module not found: 'react-google-charts' in /....

Could it be that this library is not compatible with create-react-app? Or it does not make any sense...

Thank you for any light or guide with this issue.

PS: 
Node is v6.2.2, npm is 3.9.5, Create React App "react-scripts": "0.9.5"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [npm install documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install) there is no such flag as `-s`. There is, however, `--save` or its alias `-S`. Note that it is a capital letter.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I installed yarn (npm install -g yarn) and executed the command: yarn add react-google-charts.

This way it worked as expected (I do not know the reason of the different behaviour).